# How to integrate odoo with azure blob storage?

Tags: azure, integration, azure-blob-storage, odoo, odoo-10

I am trying to integrate my odoo with azure blob storage, how can I do that?

Comment: https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/apps/bitnami.odoo?tab=Overview  please have an eye on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should checkout the capabilities of odoo on their documentation page: https://docs.bitnami.com/azure/faq/ 
There is a section of the supported capabilities in Azure as bellow:

> The Bitnami Launchpad for Microsoft Azure creates the following resources in your Microsoft Azure account:
>   A storage account for each region in which the user launches an instance.
>   Application images are added to that storage account when the user launches instances.
>   Machine disks are created in that storage account when the user launches instances.
>   A resource group with the rest of the resources needed by the instance.
>   A resource group for the various storage accounts.

Source: https://docs.bitnami.com/azure/faq/